# Enum usage with switch-case in C

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum gender {male, female};

int main () {

enum gender choice;

printf("Your gender: ");
scanf("%u", &choice);

switch(choice)
{
    case male: printf("You're a man."); break;
    case female: printf("You're a woman."); break;
    default: printf("Try again.");
}

return 0;
}
```

It doesn't matter what i write to console, it shows me 'male' case, 'You're a man.'. I've tried to write case's with quotes and single quotes but it's not working. Can you help me? That's my first question here and also sorry for my English if i had any mistakes.

Comment: `scanf("%u", &choice);` ==> `if (scanf("%u", &choice) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "unable to scanf.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: `male` and `female` are symbols, the don't exist anymore once the program is compiled and running, just as variable names don't exist any more either. Try input `0` or `1` instead of `male` or `female`.

Comment: What is an example of the input you are entering? What is the return value of the `scanf()` call? Note that the `"%u"` specifier means an unsigned integer value, and that `scanf()` will never interpret the enum identifiers.

Comment: @FredLarson he's entering `male` or `female`

Comment: @FredLarson i've used "%u" because it didn't work with "%s" and "%d". I've searched my problem here and they said me to use "%u". What should I use instead of "%u"?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: For "male", the output would actually be correct. But it is likely that the OP is trying to enter "female" and expecting it to output "You're a woman." Or entering "nonbinary" and expecting it to output "Try again."

Comment: @Dragesia: There is no format specifier for `scanf()` that will do what you appear to be expecting. You would have to input a string and interpret it yourself.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Wow, thanks man it worked. So I can't use strings in switch-case? Because I used enum to use switch-case with strings.

Comment: @Dragesia no, you cannot use strings in a switch/case __and__ more importantly you cannot use symbols of your code during runtime.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers)

> 4 Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
> type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
> implementation-defined,128) but shall be capable of representing the
> values of all the members of the enumeration.

It means that internally an object of an enumeration type is not necessary stored as an object of the type int or unsigned int. It can be stored internally as an object of the type char.

So this call of scanf

```
scanf("%u", &choice);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You need to use an intermediate variable of the type unsigned int and after the call of scanf with this variable assign its integer value to the object choice.

Another approach is for example to declare an object of the type char and ask the user to enter either 'm' for male of 'f' for female After that you can convert it either to the value 0 or 1.

For example

```
char c = 0;
scanf( "%c", &c );

if ( c == 'm' ) c = 0;
else if ( c == 'f' ) c = 1;
else c = 2;

choice = c;
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much.